# Question regarding MS Teams bot framework button

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I was wondering whether its possible to put multiple types (imback and openURL) in just one button?

Example:
I have a config for an openurl button below:

```
{
 'type': 'Action.OpenUrl',
 'wrap': True,
 'title': 'link',
 'url': 'youtube.com'
}
```

Here is my config for submit (imback) button:

```
{
 'type' : 'Action.Submit',
 'title' : value,
 'wrap': True,
 'data' : {
  'msteams": {
   'type': 'imBack',
   'value': 'open url'
  }
 }
}
```

Is there a bot framework feature that combines both of the above functionalities in just one button press?

I attempted to combine it under the same button, but when I press the button, it ignores the action.Submit and instead acts as an action.openUrl.

Comment: No, it is not possible from what I know. However, I've added the `microsoft-teams` tag to your question. Perhaps there is a workaround someone from that team might know.

Comment: Noted on this steven. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to combine multiple types of actions (like 'imBack' and 'openUrl') in a single button. Each button can only perform one action at a time.